# "map"pings in syntax files shows on startup

Tags: key-bindings, syntax

in my project I have different kinds of files. For every filetype I created a ~/.vim/syntax/[type].vim file for e.g. highlighting and key mappings. In every filetype I have a footer line with

```
 # vim:syn=[type]
```

Now I switch from VIM 7.3.547 to 8.0.707. When I now open a file vim shows me on startup all key mappings I defined in the syntax file.

```
map <silent> <C-F>    :!/home/www-data/.vim/syntax/layout-formater.pl<CR>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Then I have to press the Enter key before I can edit the file. It shows only the mappings, not the highlight definition or other thing I defined in the syntax file. And only the mappings from the syntax file, not the mappings in my ~/.vimrc file.

Does anyone know, how I can avoid this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you give an example of one your syntax files? Also, syntax files are meant to be exclusively for highlighting; local maps, options, etc are meant to be placed in ftplugins (i typically use after/ftplugin). You may also find with your upgrade that you don’t need some of your syntax files, as vim comes with many

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid this by using the right files: [`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)

```
*41.12* Writing a filetype plugin   *write-filetype-plugin* *ftplugin*

A filetype plugin is like a global plugin, except that it sets options and
defines mappings for the current buffer only.  See |add-filetype-plugin| for
how this type of plugin is used.
```

So keep your command related to syntax in your syntax file and your mappings to your ftplugin `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/[type].vim`.

Also if I understand your mapping properly you probably want to read [`:h 'formatprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatprg%27) or [`:h 'equalprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27equalprg%27), it's always better to use the built-in mechanisms to do this kind of things. And you also should not use `map`: Always use the non recursive version `noremap` and specify the mode `nnoremap` (unless you know what you are doing) it might save you a lot of debugging in the futur.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That was the right approach to the solution. But my vim won't read the filetype plugins in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin. It needs the directory ~/.vim/after/plugin or ~/.vim/plugin. But now it works perfect. Thanks again!